# Boost scoped_lock failed every time

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-mutex

In a class, I want to use a mutex over a function like this

```
void Agent::notify(Packet& packet, Peer peer) {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);
    ...
}
```

No problem at the compilation process. But when I execute the program, boost always fail at this line saying :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
Abandon (core dumped)
```

I try to use `lock()` or `unlock` methods, but the same problem. When I use `try_lock` it doesn't failed by the condition is always false.

Searching on internet I found this https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9307 .

But I think the problem is my program but I don't see where. In my tests there is only one thread that go in this function.

Comment: how is `mutex_` declared/defined? is it locked recursively?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the program the threads that use the mutex need to be at the same *level*. Yet the thread that created this error was the main thread. Not a created one.