# What does mutex lock fail with invalid argument mean?

Tags: c++, boost

This code is called in my main process and compiles fine, but when executed always throws the error below.

```
bounded_buffer<MyData> bb(200);
Producer<bounded_buffer<MyData> > producer(&bb);

boost::thread produce(producer); // throws on this line
```

Here is the error that always appears when executing.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'  
what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
```

The code for 'class bounded_buffer' is exactly as shown on this boost example page ... http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/circular_buffer/example/circular_buffer_bound_example.cpp

I found this page here which seems to show the exact same thing, but I was unable to understand the answer given. [Boost scoped_lock failed everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660519/boost-scoped-lock-failed-everytime)

Update:
Here is what Producer::operator() currently does when the functor is called. And my intentions for what I want this thread to do.

```
void operator() () {
    //init();
    //read();

    // this line just a test
    m_container->push_front(value_type());

    /*Eventually will do the following:
    while (1) {
         read_from_usb_device();
         // then store data in global buffer (bb)
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Does it really throw at that line? Creating the thread does not use the mutex. What do you do after creating the thread? I suspect `bb` gets destroyed while the thread is still running.

Comment: I don't see a join on the thread. Are you sure bb isn't going out of scope?

Comment: @StenSoft - If I comment out the thread line, I don't get that error. The overloaded operator() currently just puts data on a global buffer (bb) but will eventually run a loop reading data from a device.

Comment: @zdan - When the user plans to end the thread, then I'll wrap that up in another function when commanded to do so.

Comment: @Ender You don't get the error because it won't start the thread at all. It doesn't mean the exception is thrown there.

Comment: Please show what the function does after the thread gets created.

Comment: @StenSoft Updated with what the thread should do after creation.

Comment: @Ender I wanted to know what you do after `boost::thread produce(producer);`?

Comment: @StenSoft Nothing at the moment. It just runs that code and then the function returns void. It's basically a state who's entire purpose is to start this instance and thread it so they can run in the background.

Comment: @StenSoft - I think maybe I'm misunderstanding the overloading operator(). I put a forever counting loop inside it, and there was no crash. So the functor didn't instantiate the way I thought? Or did and was then gone?

Comment: @Ender If you put forever counting loop, the function will never get to locking the mutex but the mutex will be destroyed anyway.

Comment: @StenSoft Ok, ran it again and it counted for a bit, then crashed w/ same error. The mutex should lock in that call to m_container->push_front(value_type()) ... the boost bounded_buffer example has a function push_front which does the locking in the main buffer, not in the functor of the producer.

Comment: @Ender `m_container` points to destroyed object when `push_front` is called

Comment: @StenSoft - I'm sure you're right. I'm just trying to get past these compile errors which were the original errors I saw before changing things a bit when trying to tie in the example code. Doing what you have brought them all back. Once I understand it, I won't to forget to mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @Ender: Adding `produce.join();` won't add any compile errors. Using `shared_ptr` means you need to change `Producer` and `Consumer` to accept `shared_ptr<Buffer>` instead of `Buffer*`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77141/discussion-between-ender-and-stensoft).

Comment: @StenSoft - As much as I'd like to, chat is blocked here at my work. I could move elsewhere, but it would be another hour till I could get there.

Comment: Ok, I'm moving locations, if you happen to be on chat then, great, otherwise, thanks so much for the help. I'll continue this in about an hour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function returns and `bb` gets destroyed but the thread is still running. And when `m_container` tries to use the mutex, it (along with the whole `m_container`) no longer exists.

You need to wait for the thread to end before you can destroy any data it uses:

```
boost::thread produce(producer);
produce.join();
```

Or you need to pass the ownership of the data to the thread, eg. using `std::shared_ptr` (if you want to share the buffer with `Consumer` as in the Boost example but unlike the example not joining the threads):

```
auto bb = std::make_shared<bounded_buffer<MyData> >(200);
Producer<bounded_buffer<MyData> > producer(bb);
Consumer<bounded_buffer<MyData> > consumer(bb);
boost::thread produce(producer);
boost::thread consume(consumer);
```